# What tense should I use when putting deceased and living characters together?

Tags: tenses

- Let's say George is deceased. He **liked** the color red.
- Let's say Sally is still living. She **likes** the color red.

How would I combine these two ideas? I am looking for something like *"George and Sally liked/likes the color red."* Would I have to put these two thoughts in different sentences?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you put deceased characters together with living ones, you'll only need to worry about the living ones getting tense. :)

Comment: @KannE That's a work around I didn't think of! You might want to post it as an answer

Comment: George and Sally like the color red, but George doesn't anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is just to use one verb per person:

> George liked, and Sally likes, the color red.